# appending string horizontally in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to C# and trying a demo program in this program my intended output is:

```
Id     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Roll # 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

and this is what I have tried :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("Id ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(i+" ");
    }
    sb.AppendLine();
    sb.Append("Roll# ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(i + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sb);
}
```

though it gives me desired output but here I have to iterate through for loop twice. Is there any way by which only iterating once I can get the same output, using some string formatting of C#?

Comment: You can use 2 StringBuilders and then print their content to the Console in the same order

Comment: Build the numbers once and prepend id and roll # in 2 separate stings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done without *explicit* looping, using [Enumerable.Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=netframework-4.8) to *"generate a sequence of integral numbers within a specified range"*, along with [string.Join()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8) to concatenate the previously created range with the string `" "`  :

```
// using System.Linq;

string range = string.Join(" ", Enumerable.Range(1, 10)); // "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10"
sb.AppendLine($"Id {range}");
sb.AppendLine($"Roll# {range}");
```

---

If you really want to use a `for` loop to build your sequence, you can build your own `Range` method such as :

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Range(int min, int max)
{
    if (min > max)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The min value can't be greater than the max");
    }
    for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)
    {
        yield return i;
    }
}
```

And then `Join` like previously :

```
var range = string.Join(" ", Range(1, 10));
sb.AppendLine($"Id {range}");
sb.AppendLine($"Roll# {range}");
```

---

Or build an array/List/whatever collection and then use `string.Join()` :

```
var arr = new int [10];
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    arr[i - 1] = i;
}

string range = string.Join(" ", arr);
sb.AppendLine($"Id {range}");
sb.AppendLine($"Roll# {range}");
```

---

Or directly build a string in the loop :

```
var sbRange = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    sbRange.Append($"{i} ");
}
// You can use a string and trim it (there is a space in excess at the end)
string range = sbRange.ToString().Trim();

sb.AppendLine($"Id {range}");
sb.AppendLine($"Roll# {range}");
```

Comment: Well... under that hood, its looping ;)

Comment: Just to be clear: There is still a loop. 3 Actually. It is just loops you did not have to write.

Comment: Yes, it's still a loop under the hood, let me rephrase that a bit

Comment: @Cid that involves Linq concepts can you please give me a logic with for loop and uses single StringBuilder basically I want to append the new character (or column) horizontally

Comment: @Cid can we replace range with foreach loop just in case if I want there list values? please guide

Comment: @NetSurfer I added more ways to do that

Comment: @Christopher what are the 3 loops in the first example ?

Comment: @Cid Oh, I did not see he made this via concatenation. So he did not need a loop inside WriteLine. Unless of course there is a loop that goes over the string elements.

Comment: Is there anyway by which we can append two stringbuilders horizontally?

Comment: `sb1.Append(sb2);`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 1, use 2 `StringBuilder` instances:

```
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
sb1.Append("Id ");
sb2.Append("Roll# ");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    sb1.Append(i + " ");
    sb2.Append(i + " ");
}
Console.WriteLine(sb1);
Console.WriteLine(sb2);
```

Comment: You only need 1 and just append it to id and roll #

Comment: can we create a logic which uses only one StringBuilder

Answer (score 1):

This will always require at least 3 loops:

- One for the creation for the array.
- One for each WriteLine.

At best you can have somebody elses code do the looping *for* you.

Unless you are interested in pulling stunts like manually inserting the Newline into a really long string, there is no way to save even a single loop. But such a thing is just unreliable and should not be atempted.

It honestly sounds a lot like a Speed Question, and for those we have the [speed rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). You should read it either way, but can skip part 1.

The only improovement I can think of is building those strings with a stringbuilder. String concatenation in loops can be a bit troublesome. But on this scale it works either way.