# Is there any way to append StringBuilder horizontally in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, stringbuilder

I am trying to append two `StringBuilders` so that they produce something like:

```
Device #  1   2   3
Pt.Name  ABC DEF GHI
```

what I have tried is:

```cs
class Program
{
    class Device
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string PatName { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var datas = new List<Device>
        {
            new Device { ID = 1, PatName = "ABC" },
            new Device { ID = 2, PatName = "DEF" },
            new Device { ID = 3, PatName = "GHO" }
        };

        // there is a collection which has all this information
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("{0} {1}", "Device #", "Pt.Name").AppendLine();
        foreach (var data in datas)
        {
            var deviceId = data.ID;
            var patName = data.PatName;
            sb.AppendFormat("{0} {1}", deviceId, patName).AppendLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb);
    }
}
```

but it is printing it in vertical manner, like

```
Device #  Pt.Name
1 ABC
2 DEF
3 GHI
```

and if I remove that last `AppendLine();` it is appending it at the end in the same line.

I want to use only one stringbuilder followed by only one foreach loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59397428/appending-string-horizontally-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3):

1.You could do it like:

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("Device #");
foreach(var data in datas)
    sb.Append($" {data.deviceId}");
sb.Append("PT.Name");
foreach(var data in datas)
    sb.Append($" {data.PatName}");
```

2.if you want to loop only once then you can use 2 `StringBuilder`s:

```
StringBuilder sb1=new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sb2=new StringBuilder();

sb1.Append("Device #");
sb2.Append("Pt.Name");
foreach(var data in datas)
{
    sb1.Append($" {data.deviceId}");
    sb2.Append($" {data.patName}");
}
sb1.Append(sb2.ToString());
```

3.You could also use `string.Join()` which also relies on `StringBuilder` to write a one-liner but however this way you have extra select statements:

```
string result = $"Device # {string.Join(" ",datas.Select(x => x.deviceId))}\r\nPt.Name {string.Join(" ",datas.Select(x => x.patName))}";
```

Answer (score 1):

I love your question because it is based on avoiding these two assumption, 1) that strings are always printed left to right and 2) newlines always result in advancing the point of printing downwards.<sup>[1]</sup>

Others have given answers that will probably meet your needs, but I wanted to write about why your way of thinking won’t work. The assumptions above are so engrained into people’s thinking about how strings and terminals work that I'm sure many people taught your question was odd or even naïve, I did at first.

StringBuilder doesn’t print strings to the screen. Somewhere I suspect you are calling Console.Write to print the string. StringBuilder allows you to convert non-string variables as strings and to concatenate strings together in a more efficient way than String.Format and the + operator, see [Immutability and the StringBuilder class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8#Immutability).

When you are done using StringBuilder what you have is a string of characters. It’s called a string because it is a 1D structure, one character after each other. There is nothing special about the new line characters in the string,<sup>[2]</sup> they are just characters in the list. There is nothing in the string that specifies the position the characters other that that each one comes after the previous one. When you do something like Console.Write the position of the character on the screen is defined by the implementation of that method, or the implements of the terminal, or both. They follow the conventions of our language, i.e. each character is to the right of the previous one. When Console.Write you encounters a newline it then prints the following character in the first position of the line below the current one.

If you are using String, StringBuilder and Console you can write code to create a single string with the pieces of test in the places you want so that when Console.Write follows the left to write, top to bottom conventions your text will appear correctly. This is what the other answers here do.

Alternately you could find a library which gives you more control over when text is printed on the screen. These were very popular before Graphical User Interfaces when people build interactive applications in text terminals. Two examples I remember are CRT for Pascal and Ncurses for C. If you want to investigate this approach I’d suggest doing some web searches or even another question here. Most terminal applications you see at banks, hospitals and airlines use such a library running on a VAX.

---

[1] This may be differently in systems setup for languages which are not like English, or not like Latin.

[2] The character or characters which reprsent a new line are different on different operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

normally you cannot horizontally append to the right side of stringbuilder so maybe you roll your own extension method such as

```
static class SbExtensions
{
    public static StringBuilder AppendRight(this StringBuilder sb, string key, string value)
    {
        string output = sb.ToString();
        string[] splitted = output.Split("\n");

        splitted[0] += key.PadRight(10, ' ');
        splitted[1] += value.PadRight(10, ' ');
        output = string.Join('\n', splitted);
        return new StringBuilder(output);
    }
}
```

**simple solution:**

```
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder(columns);
foreach(var data in datas)
{
    sb2 = sb.AppendRight(data.ID.ToString(), data.PatName);
}
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

**complex one:** dynamic
just another solution using `MathNet.Numerics` library at https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/

introduce an array property in your Entity class

```
class Device
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PatName { get; set; }

    public string[] Array
    {
        get
        {
            return new string[] { ID.ToString(), PatName };
        }
    }
}
```

then in main method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var datas = new List<Device>
    {
        new Device { ID = 1, PatName = "ABC" },
        new Device { ID = 2, PatName = "DEF" },
        new Device { ID = 3, PatName = "GHO" }
    };

    var MatrixValues = datas
        .SelectMany(x => x.Array)
        .Select((item, index) => new KeyValuePair<double, string>(Convert.ToDouble(index), item)).ToArray();
    var matrixIndexes = MatrixValues.Select(x => x.Key);
    var M = Matrix<double>.Build;
    var C = M.Dense(datas.Count, datas.First().Array.Count(), matrixIndexes.ToArray());
    var TR = C.Transpose();


    string columns = "Device #".PadRight(10, ' ') + "\n" + "Pt.Name".PadRight(10, ' ');
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(columns);
    for (int i = 0; i < TR.Storage.Enumerate().Count(); i += 2)
    {
        sb = sb.AppendRight(MatrixValues[i].Value, MatrixValues[i + 1].Value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

yea and those references

```
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
```

Output

[image]

**PS:** this may not be your desired solution as it is creating multiple string builders when you append new data

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going:

### Code

```
StringBuilder deviceSB = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder patNameSB = new StringBuilder();

deviceSB.Append("Device #".PadRight(9));
patNameSB.Append("Pt.Name".PadRight(9));

foreach (var data in datas)
{
    deviceSB.Append($"{data.Device}".PadLeft(2).PadRight(4));
    patNameSB.Append($"{data.PatName} ");
}

deviceSB.AppendLine();
deviceSB.Append(patNameSB);
```

Or optional without loop

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder("Device # ".PadRight(9));
StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder("Pt.Name ".PadRight(9));

s1 = s1.AppendJoin(String.Empty, datas.Select(x => x.Device.PadLeft(2).PadRight(4)));
s2 = s2.AppendJoin(' ', datas.Select(x => x.PatName));

result = result.Append(s1).AppendLine().Append(s2);
```

Note that i took the idea of the second option from @AshkanMobayenKhiabani, but instead of using `strings` i stick to `StringBuilder` since it is much more performant than using `strings`!

---

### Output

Both of previous options offer the same output:

[image]

Comment: I think your best bet is using 1 StringBuilder/string you concat to per Display Line. The rest would be just basic grouping. And hopinf for a fixed width Output Font/Display.